# Accessibility for Silverlight Combobox Items

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-3.0, combobox, accessibility

In my Silverlight page I have a combobox.  In the code-behind I'm filling the combobox items like so:

```
this.ProblemList.Items.Add(Strings.Review_SelectProblem);
this.ProblemList.Items.Add(Strings.Review_IncorrectCharacters);
this.ProblemList.Items.Add(Strings.Review_MissingText);
...
this.ProblemList.SelectedIndex = 0; //Set the default selection
```

Elsewhere, in my XAML page I am providing accessibility (for the disabled) to other non-combobox controls by doing this:

```
AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Strings.Review_Access_ParagraphCorrect}"
```

I'd like to provide Accessibility to my combobox items but the only way I've been able to find is like so:

```
AutomationProperties.SetLabeledBy(this.nameInput, this.nameLabel);
```

The problem with this is that my combobox items must have a name.  How do I assign a name to my combobox items programmaticly or how can I provide accessibility in the code behind with out referencing the name of the combobox items?

Thank you for your help,

Aaron

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use something like this:

```
ComboBoxItem tmpItem = new ComboBoxItem();
tmpItem.Content = Strings.Review_SelectProblem;
tmpItem.Name = Strings.Review_SelectProblem;
this.ProblemList.Items.Add(tmpItem);
```

I hope I understood you correctly.